# How do we invoke a class not more than a TPS limit

Tags: java, spring, api

There is a Java Class that I have

```
Class CallXYZAPI {
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
}
```

How do we honour that the API gets called not more than X times per second

i.e #method1Calls + #method2Calls + #method3Calls <= X

I am looking for the most simplistic way to do this. Is it possible in a non intrusive way(without modifying the class)

Comment: Look up "token bucket rate limiting." Guava's is easy enough to use, but there are others.

Comment: Check https://dzone.com/articles/detailed-explanation-of-guava-ratelimiters-throttl